# The inequation $\lfloor x\rfloor^2-\lfloor x\rfloor-6>0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, quadratics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

The question is to find the solutions to this inequation
$$\lfloor x\rfloor^2 - \lfloor x\rfloor - 6 > 0$$

On factorising I got
$$(\lfloor x\rfloor-3)(\lfloor x\rfloor+2)>0$$
so $\lfloor x\rfloor>3$ or $\lfloor x\rfloor>-2$ and so on

But in the text book the solution goes like this

> $\lfloor x\rfloor>3$ so $x\ge 4$ and  $\lfloor x\rfloor<-2$ so $x <-2$
>   therefore domain is...

Notice that the textbook has reversed the second inequality and it turns out to be correct as I checked it in wolfram alpha.

Can anyone please explain why the book reversed $\lfloor x\rfloor>-2$ into $\lfloor x\rfloor<-2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "On factorising I got $(\lfloor x\rfloor-3)(\lfloor x\rfloor +2)>0$, **so** $\lfloor x\rfloor>3$ or $\lfloor x\rfloor >-2$ and so on"

The bold "so" is wrong: for $a\le b\in\Bbb R$,

> $$(t-a)(t-b)>0\iff t< a\vee t>b$$

You applied it incorrectly to the case $a=-2$, $b=3$

Comment: can i say a <t v b>t

Comment: by the way thanks for answering and correcting my mistake.

Comment: @user453135 No, it is not the same thing. For instance, when $a<b$, all $t\in\Bbb R$ verify that condition.